# Blanco o Blanca Tequila

Tags: adjetivos

I've often seen young tequila referred to as blanco tequila or tequila blanco. It appears on the labels of bottles so I would assume the manufacturer would have made sure of the grammar. I would have thought it should be blanca given an adjective should match the noun. There are three types of tequila: blanco/a, reposado, and añejo. Is it because blanco refers to a type of tequila and not the color that blanco is used or is the usage just incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After posting the question, it occurred to me that tequila may be a masculine noun. I looked it up and verified that was the case.

Comment: *Rectissimo*, es **el** tequila; es decir es masculino y por lo tanto lo correcto es **blanco**. Ya podés marcarlo como resuelto

Answer (score 0):

Tequila is a word with masculine genre since is a type of drink (also masculine). And it means white since the first distillation from agave w=gives you a high alcohol content and no color due to the containers for aging, having the names REPOSADO or AÑEJO

Comment: Are all drinks really masculine? Cerveza, agua for instance.

Comment: I recently spoke to a native Spanish about this. She told me almost all drinks are masculine

Comment: Margarita is feminine, but you'll probablly ask for "un tequila Margarita" that will make it masculine again. La cachaza (cachaça) is feminine but it's borrowed from Portuguese... Good question